# FATFQ (First Answer the Fine Question)

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

This question is **not a duplicate**, it is not about right and wrong answers and questions, it is about whether an acronym for **sloppy answers to good questions** would be useful, and I propose one that seems reasonably polite, more than some well known acronym for the opposite case (RTFM for sloppy questions).
This is obviously based on the assumption that there are also sloppy answers, not only sloppy questions.

---

More often than expected I see that questions like
"... how do I do x in Y ..."?
even **when they are clearly and well specified** get some replies that do NOT answer the question at all and go like:
"In Y doing x is bad style"
"Why would you want do to x?"
"Why are you using Y"?
"Tell me the story of your life so we can understand why you wrongly chose language/tool Y rather than Z that is more ..."
...

Such replies would be somehow acceptable if they came along with the requested answer, most of the times there is no answer, this is the case I am writing about (and about clear, well specified questions)

Such annoying non-answers seem nearly as frequent as sloppy questions.
For sloppy questions there is RTFM.
For this annoying non-answers I am not aware of useful acronyms, so I propose **FATFQ**, which seems not only appropriate but also rather "open" and kind, relative to this kind of non-answers:
it is not JATFQ or OATFQ (Just Ask.../ Only Ask ...) it is "**First** Ask The Fine Question", after that free to explain how right your tools and vision of the world are and how wrong the question is, but first, before the sermon, please answer the fine question, maybe by saying that you do not see any way to do x in Y.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about _comments_, not _answers_. If someone really writes a rude comment like Read The Fine Manual first please, you may flag it as such.

Comment: Maybe they expect an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it is pretty frustrating to find out it is *after* you answered **The Fine Question**

Comment: I talk about answers that do not (even try to) answer the question. 
I do not talk about rudeness or kindness.

Comment: @user778806 Can you link some examples into your questions please? I can't believe that such _non-answers_ would survive very long.

Comment: @rene Read what I wrote: is a question, ***well specified*** as I wrote, 
the context is sloppy answers, not sloppy question. What is expected is an answer, not someone who does not even try to answer but starts a (technical) sermon.

Comment: The commentors or the answerers beg to differ and often for good reasons. If you don't get the answers you want or expect, blame the question not those that spend their free time to provide their knowledge, experience and reasoning.

Comment: @user778806 Sometimes a technical sermon is what the question needs. The user asking had to ask, which means they didn't have the needed expertise to solve the problem, so there might be solutions/problems they are not aware of. Also, the answer is supposed to help other users as well.

Comment: @gnat note that this question is to propose an acronym, not to discuss the right or wrong way to ask and answer

Comment: We don't need that acronym as the question where you want to apply shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @Modus  You are ignoring that I clearly set the scope "question clearly specified"

Comment: @rene are acronyms useless and should be condemned in online conversations? Or only acronyms for this case? (sloppy non-answers to good questions)

Comment: @user778806 I am not. A question can be clearly specified from the viewpoint of the user asking, but it can be obvious to a user preparing to answer that the question is asked on a wrong premise.

Comment: You keep hammering on *good questions*. Let me hammer back by repeating myself as well: It is pretty frustrating to find out after the fact that you have answered an unclear question. We don't need acronyms and specially we don't need the one you propose. Beyond that I believe such acronyms come to exist naturally, not because the  acronym invention board approved them.

Comment: @ your legitimate opinion. One last comment: sloppy non-answers waste time as much as sloppy questions.

Comment: @user778806 _"more than some well known acronym for the opposite case (RTFM for sloppy quesions)"_ This would be considered rude, and flagged.

Comment: @rene I am not hammering, my question is about that scope, if you ignore it you are not answering or commenting my question.

Comment: @user778806 You were asked to clarify your question, and to link some example question and answers into your question that would support your point why we would need such acronym. Do you see what's gone wrong?

Comment: In any case, FATFQ will not be useful for the same reason RTFM is not useful and should be flagged: it is rude.

Comment: Agree with deprecation of RTFM and anything that is unpolite. Acronyms are not strictly necessary on platforms like this but I think they may still be useful, even here. General consideration, not about the one I proposed.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  gone wrong :-) ? I have an idea/opinion, I posted it, got replies that I consider useful even more considering that originally I would have disagreed with them, from replies I learned/realized better the difference between stackoverflow  and other forums (started with NNTP in 1993 and use this marginally). For me has gone well. If I were someone with ego problems living for "reputation" maybe would have "gone wrong", luckily am not in that sad perspective/situation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't need to invent acronyms for sloppy answers as much as we don't need RTFM for sloppy questions.

A sloppy answer deserves a down vote, nothing more, nothing less. If the answer is missing the point of the question and someone can fit in 500 characters what is wrong with the answer in the context of the question, by all means do so. Do not use *-1 sloppy answer* or any other (acronym) noise. If you're not prepared to engage with the OP, don't comment.

Vote and move on.

Comment: The tone of your post helps put your views in perspective.

Comment: Thanks. I always try to really get to the core of the issue at hand and then provide a competitive answer.

Comment: what is a competitive answer?

Comment: an answer that is better then the existing answer(s)

Comment: Done, I tend to agree more with the other but this is more in scope, the other speaks about comments and new users so bad questions or expectations,  that I explicitly (and, I believe, clearly) excluded,

Answer (score 6):

All (newer) users suspect they write *fine*, *well formulated* and *well specified* questions, without caring about site policies, where it's well defined what constitutes **a good question**.

Also all (newer) users demand that their personal problems are solved in 1st place, without caring about their questions usefulness for future research.

As mentioned I believe you're talking about *comments* and not *answers*, since an answer like

> "Why would you want do to x?"

won't survive very long at any site.

If someone asks such in a comment, they want you to clarify your question (which is the mere purpose of comments). So you simply should do that, and edit your question to make it clearer.

I don't see any problem with it, or the need for YAA (I leave it open to you to figure what this acronym should mean).

Comment: The scope has been clearly described, clear questions and sloppy answers. Discussing what is a goood question is another matter, rather complex and somehow subjective

Comment: @user778806 _"Please FATFQ, ie within its scope"_ I did: _I don't see any problem with it, or the need for YAA (I leave it open to you to figure what this acronym should mean)._

Comment: Yes, you are right, you aswered in scope, noticed it late as am doing other things, sorry about it. Let me mark your answer as useful.